# Quartz and rabbitMQ, which is the difference?

Tags: rabbitmq, quartz-scheduler

Quartz and RabbitMQ, which is the difference between these technologies?
Can they be used together?
Could these technologies be installed on the hardware that hosts the web server or is it better to have dedicated hardware for them?

Comment: It would have been great if there had been any amount of background or research in the question. What are you trying to achieve? How did these two names occur to you? What have you tried to find an answer before asking here?

Answer (score 9):

Let's first assume you mean [Quartz, a scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org), not [Quartz, a Mac OS X graphics layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_%28graphics_layer%29). ;)

- [RabbitMQ](http://rabbitmq.com) is a message queue. Message queues make sure messages reach their destination, persisting during downtimes and load-balancing between multiple worker processes. You generally want a message queue if you have several processes doing different types of work and you need a way to distribute the work load.
- Quartz is a scheduler. Schedulers make sure events happen at the right time, possibly ensuring one event is properly executed before another may start, or catching up with the schedule after a downtime. You generally want a scheduler if the basic OS capabilities like crontab etc. are not sufficient for your needs.

Combining the two concepts can be powerful: have the scheduler trigger events or chains of events into the message queue, and have many workers listen on their respective queues to perform the assigned tasks.

Depending on what you want to achieve, it may be perfectly ok to have everything on the same machine. When you experience poor performance you can decide if you want a bigger machine or distribute the work load on many smaller ones.

You may want to look at the tutorials on RabbitMQ's and Quartz's web sites to see if either or both things are right for your purpose.